# (Java Multi threading) How to pass parameter in multithreading?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am getting an error( in last 5 lines) when i pass a parameter in the start() method. The error says: method start() in type thread is not applicable for argument (int). What is the right way to do it?

This program is about printing odd/even numbers using multi-threading in Java.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class odd extends Thread
{
public void run(int y){
    System.out.println("Odd numbers are:");
    for (int i=0;i<=y;i++)
    {
        if (i%2!=0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
}
}

class even extends Thread{

public void run(int x)
{
    System.out.println("Even Numbers are");
    for (int i=0; i<=x; i++)
    {
        if (i%2==0)
        {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
    }
 }

 }


  class Star{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("Enter No. upto which even-odd should be printed");
    Scanner var=new Scanner(System.in);
    int vary= var.nextInt();

    odd money=new odd();
    even honey=new even();

    money.start(vary);

    Thread.sleep(5000);
    honey.start(vary);

}
}
```

Comment: Normally I pass any needed parameters in the constructor, then just call `start()`.

Comment: You should declare `jo` and `yo` since you want to initialize them (a please, put Uppercase to your class names, see the CamelCase notation.

Comment: Change the constructor of `yo` to accept the integer

Comment: And hint. Jo and yo are absolutely meaningless names! Better use names that mean something.

Comment: @GhostCat Thanks for the suggestion, i am new to java, will use, better names for class from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are syntactical and logical errors in your program:

I have corrected your code. Below code is the correct code for printing odd/even numbers using multi-threading in Java.

```
class jo extends Thread {
    private int number;

    jo(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Odd numbers are:");
        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
            if (i % 2 != 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

class yo extends Thread {

    private int number;

    yo(int number) {
        this.number = number;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Even Numbers are");
        for (int i = 0; i <= number; i++) {
            if (i % 2 == 0) {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }

}
import java.util.Scanner;

class Star {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("Enter No. upto which eve-od should be printed");
        Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
        int vary = var.nextInt();
        jo money = new jo(vary);
        yo honey = new yo(vary);

        money.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        honey.start();

    }

}
```

**Corrections done:**

1. In class Star, there was a syntax error when you were creating object of class jo

2.To achieve multithreading, you need to override run method of thread class. The correct signature of run method is   `public void run() { //logical code will go here }` run method does not accept any input arguments.

3.To start execution of thread you need to invoke the start method of Thread class. It looks like `public void start()`. start method does not accept any input arguments.

4.I have done the logical correction in your code in jo and yo class. use % operator to check a given number is even or odd. % operator returns remainder, if a remainder comes zero when a number is divided by 2, it means it is a even number else it is odd.

You can run shared code to check the outputs.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 4):

The standard way to do this is to

1. declare one or more member variables in the thread class to hold parameters
2. declare a constructor in the thread class to receive and store these parameters
3. pass the parameters when *instantiating* the thread class

For your example:

```
class Jo extends Thread
{
    int var;
    public Jo(int var) {
        this.var = var;
    }
    public void run(int y) {
        // some code using this.var
        ...
    }
}

...

Jo money = new Jo(vary);
money.start();
```

Comment: Be careful about synchronicity issues. Wrap access to the member variable in a synchronized block.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of mistakes in the program. I am pointing them out.

1. Typos for - `jo=money` will be `jo money = new jo();`
   `money.stary(vary);` will be `money.start();`
2. Logic is wrong : To check for a number to be even or odd we must check the remainder of division operation by 2 to be 0 or not. Instead you checked the quotient. Assume 4, So 4/2 = 2, and !=0 so the code will consider it as a odd number.

   Now, if it is `a%b == 0`, it will work like this, 4%2 = 0, thus even.
3. Thread.start() does not take any parameter, so you have to create a constructor of the class to pass in the limits.

I have modified the code like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class jo extends Thread
{
    private int limit;
    
    public jo(int limit)
    {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Odd numbers are");
        
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= limit ; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 != 0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
    }
}

class yo extends Thread
{
    private int limit;
    
    public yo(int limit)
    {
        this.limit = limit;
    }
    
    public void run()
    {
        System.out.println("Even Numbers are");
        
        for (int i = 0 ; i <= limit ; i++)
        {
            if (i%2 == 0)
            {
                System.out.println(i);
            }
        }
     }
 }


class TestProject
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Enter No. upto which eve-od should be printed");
        Scanner var = new Scanner(System.in);
        int vary = var.nextInt();
        jo money = new jo(vary);
        yo honey = new yo(5vary);

        money.start();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        honey.start();

    }
}
```

I hope this will help you out.

**P.S. : Please check your naming conventions. It will be a really difficult for others to understand.**

Comment: Are we allowed to use limit(variable) inside the method run()? As limit(variable) is declared outside that method.

Comment: It is declared inside the scope of the class which makes it accessible through out the whole class (yo and jo). You can make use of it in any methods inside that class. Best practise is to make the variable decraled as private as mentioned by @Reena Upadhyay. It is a very good habit. so make `int limit` as `private int limit`

Comment: @YoMama : Was there any particular reason to making my answer not acceptable after accepting it once? Please tell me if there is anything wrong in the code for which you cancelled the acceptance or is there any other reason. Thank you.

Comment: Read the comment below @Reena Upadhyay. She asked me to choose her answer. Though all the answers were EQUALLY  good and helpful. Look..all i could do is..give my thanks and well wishes to you. I hope that should be enough.